# why integer value returns when I console.log my promise

Tags: javascript, promise

I was wondering why integer value returns when I console.log my promise.

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('hello world');
    }, 2000);
});

promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

setTimeout(() => console.log("after: ", promise), 3000);
```

**output:**

[image]

But if I remove the console.log after my promise resolves, then there isn't returned any integer. **Why** this happened?

Comment: Because [`setTimeout` returns a number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Return_value).

Comment: When you run commands in the console, their return value is logged

Comment: thanks @HereticMonkey got it

Comment: I *don't* get a number output on the terminal here and wouldn't expect to. @HereticMonkey `setTimeout` isn't being run directly on the terminal and the value of the assignment is `undefined`. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @Mark It is being run. If you're looking only at the image, you're missing the ellipses after the semicolon, which elides the rest of the code in the OP's code block that was also pasted into the console.

Comment: Got it – it's the *last* `setTimeout` thanks @HereticMonkey.

Comment: @HereticMonkey WOW!  Without your comment I was totally confused!  Along with many others, I'm sure.  But it makes sense that all the code was pasted into the console. Out of curiosity though...which browser is doing the eliding?

Comment: @Wyck This is the Firefox console.

Comment: @HereticMonkey, you need to write a full answer because your first comment alone does *not* fully explain everything that needs to be explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to explain what is happening here is to use Stack Snippets, which includes a custom implementation of a console. Here's the original code in a snippet. Click "Run code snippet" at your leisure:

```js
var promise = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function() {
        resolve('hello world');
    }, 2000);
});

promise.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});

setTimeout(() => console.log("after: ", promise), 3000);
```

Note that no number is displayed. That's because the custom implementation does not echo the return value of functions called unless they are logged via `console.log`. Almost all browsers do, even IE (v11 anyway).

So, if you were to run the following line in your console, you'd see something similar:

```
setTimeout(function () { console.log('done'); }, 100);
```

Just some number. That number is handy of course. You can pass it to `clearTimeout` to stop the timeout from occurring:

```
var id = setTimeout(function () { console.log('done'); }, 100);
clearTimeout(id);
```

That should never log "done".

So, to be clear, this has nothing to do with promises, or the `setTimeout` used inside the function passed to the promise constructor; only the last `setTimeout` call that logs the value of the `promise` variable after 3 seconds, and only in a browser console.

Oh, and at least one browser (Firefox) likes hiding the code that's running :).